# CodeBuild shows SUCCEEDED; however, it should be saying FAILED when using Packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, packer

I am running into an issue which I know has to do with my `buildspec.yml` file:

```
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.8
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Installing Packer"
      - curl -o packer.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/packer/1.7.2/packer_1.7.2_linux_amd64.zip && unzip packer.zip
      - echo "Validating Packer template"
      - ./packer validate pipeline/build/${FUNCTION}-build.json
  build:
    commands:
      - ./packer build -color=false pipeline/build/${FUNCTION}-build.json | tee build.log
  post_build:
    commands:
      # Get the ARN of our Lambda notifier
      - SLACK_ARN=$(aws cloudformation list-exports | jq -r '.["Exports"][] | select(.Name == "notify_slack_arn") | .Value')
      # Send a Slack notification
      - |
        if [ "${CODEBUILD_BUILD_SUCCEEDING}" -eq 1 ]
        then
          aws lambda invoke --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --function-name ${SLACK_ARN} --payload "{ \"LambdaInvokeEvent\": { \"message\": \"Daily AMI Build for ${FUNCTION} SUCCESSFUL!\", \"slack_url\": \"${SLACK_URL}\" } }" slack_output.log
        else
          aws lambda invoke --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --function-name ${SLACK_ARN} --payload "{ \"LambdaInvokeEvent\": { \"message\": \"Daily AMI Build for ${FUNCTION} FAILED!\", \"slack_url\": \"${SLACK_URL}\" } }" slack_output.log
        fi
      - echo "Build completed on $(date)"
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  discard-paths: no
```

So from my code that builds in CodeBuild, this is what happens:[image]

Even though it fails, CodeBuild says SUCCEEDED which is driving me nuts! It is suppose to fail and give a failing notification. Does this have to do with my `buildspec.yml` file or my bash script that is running? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that happens because of your `| tee build.log`. packer fails, but tee works, so as this being the last command executed, build stage succeeds.

Comment: Ah interesting, I'll look into this.

Comment: After removing `| tee build.log`, that did the trick in showing FAILED in CodeBuild. Thanks for the help Marcin!